# Column Chooser in Backgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jqgrid, backgrid

I am new to backgrid (and stackoverflow) and I am curious if there is any column chooser for backgrid so that user can choose what columns are to be visible in my grid.

I know there is one for jqgrid which can be seen in action here:

http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooser5.htm

If there isn't any for backgrid, any ideas on how to implement this without reloading the grid again?

One way it could be done but it requires a reload of grid like so,

> make the columns :renderable option as false , and not show the columns on initial load.
>   User selects the columns which he wants to see , then reload the Grid with new column attributes for the selected columns with renderable:true like so:

```
var grid = new Backgrid.Grid(columns: new Columns([{..renderable:true}, {...}], {
}));
```

But as you can see , I will be reloading the entire grid with the new columns though we already have this data in the DOM. I am looking forward to any ideas where in we can implement this without new Grid call

Comment: Backgrid and jqGrid are absolutely separate products. Which one you want to use?

Comment: I need one for backgrid . I gave jqgrid column chooser as an example on what the requirement is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is looking for the similar sort of implementation - they can look at  https://github.com/WRidder/Backgrid.ColumnManager

[DEMO](https://wridder.github.io/backgrid-demo/)